# While trying to ssh, pam_ldap always sends the password "INCORRECT" causing bind to fail

Tags: ssh, authentication, pam, ldap

I installed `ldap-auth-client nscd ldap-utils` on lubuntu 14.04 running on a banana pi. I can successfully bind as the user using `ldapwhoami`, but I cannot log in via ssh:

Auth.log:

```
Oct 21 02:12:05 lemaker sshd[1445]: Invalid user jonathan.fisher from 192.168.119.16
Oct 21 02:12:05 lemaker sshd[1445]: input_userauth_request: invalid user jonathan.fisher [preauth]
Oct 21 02:12:09 lemaker sshd[1445]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 21 02:12:09 lemaker sshd[1445]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=thor.corp.xxx.com 
Oct 21 02:12:09 lemaker sshd[1445]: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "cn=jonathan.fisher,ou=users,dc=corp,dc=xxx,dc=com" (Invalid credentials)
Oct 21 02:12:12 lemaker sshd[1445]: Failed password for invalid user jonathan.fisher from 192.168.119.16 port 53005 ssh2
```

This is where things get weird...
I got the crazy notion to do a tcpdump, and it's trying to bind with the literal password string as `INCORRECT`, the not the password I typed in. This seems ridiculous... what is going on?

## EDIT

```
bananapi@lemaker:~$ sudo id jonathan.fisher
id: jonathan.fisher: no such user
```

Not sure why it would be doing this... I have nsswitch.conf setup:

```
passwd: files ldap
group: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
```

Comment: Did you get any solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: So upon failure, some part of the pam stack defaults that to make sure the bind fails during an authentication fail. It indicates something else is wrong. .. I suspect in my case the pam_ldap module complied for ARM is corrupt.

Comment: I found out, in my case, that the problem was actually the keyboard. One key that was in my password didn't work anymore... So the password WAS wrong.

Comment: I had this misleading error because my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file contained `AllowUsers user1 user2 ...`, so other users were not allowed SSH access. So in my case, this pam_ldap error saying "Invalid credentials" had in fact nothing to do with ldap or the password.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem.  I had 'ldap' in my nsswitch.conf.  Everything looked correct.  The only problem was that the NSS LDAP module wasn't actually installed.  All I needed was this:

```
apt-get install libnss-ldap
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command:     `adflush`

I got this messages on server:

```
Aug 26 12:44:24 nim2-bar syslog: ssh: failed login attempt for UNKNOWN_USER from 10.214.144.11
Aug 26 12:44:24 nim2-bar sshd[18219478]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for invalid user u50385 from xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 53006 ssh2 [preauth]
Aug 26 12:44:24 nim2-bar sshd[18219478]: Disconnecting invalid user u50385 10.214.144.11 port 53006: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
```